# Authentication via headers in WCF REST service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I am new to WCF services and currently testing out things.

I have got a little REST API, which has several methods. Some of them require a user context (session), some others don't. At login, each user gets a session token. The client should supply this token and his user ID on every request *via HTTP headers*.

At the moment, I wrote a method for getting those two headers and validate the session, calling it on every method which will need a user context. This seems kinda nasty if the API gets bigger.

Is there a better approach for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage of following solutions:

1. Custom class deriving IClientMessageInspector/*IDispatchMessageInspector* for client and service respectively. Then you add its instance to MessageInspectors. Advantage of having messageInspector is that it's applied to single endpoint so regardless of having many endpoints exposed (both SOAP and REST), messageInspector can be associated only with single one. Whenever message is either received or sent, AfterReceive or BeforeSent method is invoked respectively. There you retrieve headers and if token does not match any expected you can throw an exception. Such a way out provides separation between exposed contract and background checks such as token validation.
2. Custom class deriving *IOperationInvoker*. Within custom operation invoker you explicitly call method and thanks to it you can examine headers (OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessage) before any method gets invoced. 
   I brought up only concepts, extensive information and examples can be looked up on Internet.